# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined | But points to the element when I console.log it

Tags: javascript

When I console.log img_li[i] it points to the correct element.But I get the above error while I try to check if the class of "d_on" is present in the element. The same code works for the right button(First event). But does not work for the left event. The error happens on this line *var d_check =  elem.classList.contains("d_on");*

```
<body>
    <div id="img-nav">
        <a href="#" class="arrow left"><img src="img/left.png"></a>
        <a href="#" class="arrow right"><img src="img/right.png"></a>
    </div>

<ul id="images">
    <li class="img_li d_on"><img src="img/1.jpg"></li>
    <li class="img_li"><img src="img/2.jpg"></li>
    <li class="img_li"><img src="img/3.jpg"></li>
    <li class="img_li"><img src="img/4.jpg"></li>
    <li class="img_li"><img src="img/5.jpg"></li>
    <li class="img_li"><img src="img/6.jpg"></li>
    <li class="img_li"><img src="img/7.jpg"></li>
    <li class="img_li"><img src="img/8.jpg"></li>
</ul>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var ul = document.querySelector(".images");
    var img_li = document.querySelectorAll(".img_li");
    var pointer = document.querySelector(".d_on");
    var left = document.querySelector(".left");
    var right = document.querySelector(".right");


    //right button

    right.addEventListener("click",function(){
        for(i=0; i < img_li.length; i++){
            var elem = img_li[i];
            var d_check =  elem.classList.contains("d_on");
            var elemNext = elem.nextElementSibling;

            console.log(i);

            if(i==(img_li.length)-1){
                elem.classList.remove("d_on");
                i = 0;
                img_li[0].classList.add("d_on");
                console.log("working_If");
                break;
            }

            if(d_check){
                elem.classList.remove("d_on");
                if(elemNext){
                    elemNext.classList.add("d_on");

                    break;
                }
            }// end of d_check

        }//end of loop
    });//end of event


    // left button

    left.addEventListener("click",function(){
        for(i=img_li.length; i >= 0 ; i--){
            console.log(img_li[i]);//working
            var elem = img_li[i];
            var d_check =  elem.classList.contains("d_on");
            var elemNext = elem.nextElementSibling;
            var elemPrev = elem.previousElementSibling;
        }//end of loop
    });//end of event

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

So your code have some mistakes.

1. You should not append click listeners to every `<li>` element (it is very costly performance wise). Appending listener to `<ul>` would do the job due to js mechanics know as EventBubbling. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events.
2. You should remove event listeners when they are not required anymore (removeEventListener).
3. In your first for loop (right button) you are creating GLOBAL variable `i` and assigning `0` as its value. Then in your second loop (left button) you are overwriting `i` variable value. You should not make use of global variables. The easiest fix would be to create block scoped variable 'i' using let keyword `let i = 0` and `i=img_li.length` To learn more about common bad practices look up https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode.